# Create folder and store Image by camera

Tags: java, android, camera

please read my code ask solution how to create folder

public class CameraActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

```
private static final int ACTION_TAKE_IMAGE = 1;

Button btnImage;
ImageView imageView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);

    imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    btnImage= (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCapture);
    btnImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent takeVideoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, ACTION_TAKE_IMAGE);
        }
    });
}
```

@onActivityResult start

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            try
            {
                AssetFileDescriptor imageAsset = getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(data.getData(), "r");
                FileInputStream fis = imageAsset.createInputStream();
                File root=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"/Vipul/RecordImage/");
                if (!root.exists()) {
                    System.out.println("No directory");
                    root.mkdirs();
                }

                File file;
                file=new File(root,"IMG_"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg" );

                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

                byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                int len;
                while ((len = fis.read(buf)) > 0) {
                    fos.write(buf, 0, len);
                }
                fis.close();
                fos.close();

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if(requestCode == ACTION_TAKE_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) bundle.get("data");
            imageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
        }
    }
}
```

this code work 2.3 capture Image but work  and not create folder not store in my specific folder please ask your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code

```
public class CameraActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

//    private static final int ACTION_TAKE_IMAGE = 1;

    Button btnImage;
    ImageView imageView;
    File image;
    String picturePath;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);

        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        btnImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCapture);
        btnImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(
                        android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                //Create folder
                File imagesFolder = new File(
                        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Vipul/image");
                imagesFolder.mkdirs();

                //Asign name for image
                String fname = "Pic-" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png";
                image= new File(imagesFolder, fname);

                Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(image);

                cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);

                //launch camera app with result code (forResult)
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 1);

            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bitmap bitmap;

            BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();

            picturePath=image.getAbsolutePath();

            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.getAbsolutePath(), bitmapOptions);

            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
}
```

final solution

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**

```
//declare

     int num = 0;

//.....//


//*onclik button

Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(
                android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        //Create folder
        File imagesFolder = new File(
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Myfolder");
        imagesFolder.mkdirs();

        //Asign name for image
        File image = new File(imagesFolder, "Pic" + (num +1) + ".png");
        Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(image);

        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);

        //launch camera app with result code (forResult)
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 1);


protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {

            if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            {
                //create bitmap with image

                Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(
                        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +
                                "/Myfolder/" + "Pic" + num + ".png");
                //Add bitmap to ImageView
                //Show on screen
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bMap);
 }
```

Comment: if i want capture second images than which image will be display ASPICS?

Comment: You can "click" on button again and it display on your ImageView without problem. @JATINDEVANI

Comment: Folder Is created But only Last Image is store Other Image Automatic Deleted

Comment: Ok But Only Store Last Images @ASPICAS

Comment: Of course, because it have the same name, but you can store images with differents names, for example, when you create your image name you can declare a variable  (integer)  and later add '1' on that variable. `"Pic" + (var+1) + ".png")`

Comment: Have you got it working with different names image? FinavaVipul @JATINDEVANI

Comment: Show me your LogCat Errors

Comment: Or try only put number on image name; `var=var+1;`, later on code `var+ ".png")`

Answer (score 1):

To use different name for image everytime you can use method getTimeInMillis() as `Calendar mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                String n = ""+mCalendar.getTimeInMillis();
                String fname = "Pic-" + n.substring(5) + ".png";
//Asign name for image
        File image = new File(imagesFolder, fname);
        Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(image);`

Comment: thanks @Rahul Sharma save the images but not Retrive the Image how can retrive images ?

Comment: To retrieve you need to store complete path of image in String variable then you can get bitmap from this path and use this bitmap anywhere, follow this code:

Comment: Calendar mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance(); String n = ""+mCalendar.getTimeInMillis();
String fname = "Pic-" + n.substring(5) + ".png"; String imgPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+fname;
Now where you want to retrive use this code:
Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgPath);
Now set this bitmap in your imageView:
imageView.setImageBitmap(img);